# Xcode Error Semantic error value may not respond to 'initWithFrame:image Name:'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, compiler-errors

I am getting an error in my project. I have tried plenty of solutions but to no avail.

I am getting an error Xcode Error Semantic error value may not respond to 'initWithFrame:image Name:'

I have no idea what this means and why i'm getting this warning. Please help.

Thanks

[Link](http://www.blakeloizides.co.za/testing.zip) to my project and the Updated project [link](http://www.blakeloizides.co.za/new.zip).

I'm getting the error in this line

```
GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height) imageName:imgName];
```

**GalleryScrollView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AttachmentItem.h"
#import "GalleryButton.h"

@protocol GAlleryScrollDelegate;

@interface GalleryScrollView : UIView <GalleryButtonDelegate>

{

id <GAlleryScrollDelegate> delegate;

// MAIN WINDOW WHERE YOU CAN DRAG ICONS
UIView *mainView;

UIScrollView *_scrollView;
NSMutableArray *_attachments;


NSInteger *_totalSize;

UIImageView *_recycleBin;
CGRect recycleBinFrame;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <GAlleryScrollDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *attachments;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *recycleBin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imgName;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect recycleBinFrame;

- (void) addAttachment:(AttachmentItem *)attachment withImageNamed:(NSString *)imgName;
- (void) removeAttachment:(GalleryButton *)button;
- (void) reloadData;
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName;

@end

// EVENTS IF YOU WANT TO DISABLE SOME SCROLL ON DID PRESS AND ENABLE IT ON DROP
@protocol GAlleryScrollDelegate
- (void) didPressButton;
- (void) didDropButton;
@end
```

**GalleryScrollView.m**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "GalleryScrollView.h"
#import "GalleryButton.h"

@implementation GalleryScrollView

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize mainView;
@synthesize attachments = _attachments;
@synthesize recycleBin = _recycleBin, recycleBinFrame;

int padding = 0;

#pragma mark - INIT

- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
}
return self;
}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self){
    ;
}
return self;
}
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
// INIT ATTACHMENT ARRAY
if (_attachments == nil){
    _attachments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

// SCROLL VIEW
UIScrollView *scrollTemp = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width-0, 450)];
_scrollView = scrollTemp;
_scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// RECYCLE BIN
UIImageView *imageViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge.png"]];
self.recycleBin = imageViewTemp;
self.recycleBin.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 270);

[self addSubview:_scrollView];
[self addSubview:self.recycleBin];
[scrollTemp release];
[imageViewTemp release];
 }

- (void) dealloc {
[super dealloc];

}

#pragma mark - ATTACHMENTS ADD / REMOVE

- (void) addAttachment:(AttachmentItem *)attachment withImageNamed:(NSString *)imgName
{
// SAVE ATTACHMENT
[_attachments addObject:attachment];

// RESIZE CONTENT VIEW FOR INSERTINT NEW ATTACHMENT
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([_attachments count]*70, 70);

CGFloat startX = (70.0f * ((float)[_attachments count] - 1.0f) + padding);
CGFloat startY = 370;
CGFloat width = 64;
CGFloat height = 64;

GalleryButton *btnAttachment = [[GalleryButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startX, startY, width, height) imageName:imgName];
btnAttachment.tag = [_attachments count];
btnAttachment.scrollParent = _scrollView;
btnAttachment.mainView = self.mainView;
btnAttachment.delegate = self;

if (attachment.type == 1){
}else if (attachment.type == 2){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"mozambique-wenge"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
} else if (attachment.type == 3){
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"recyclebin.png"];
    [btnAttachment addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

[_scrollView addSubview:btnAttachment];
[btnAttachment release];

}

- (void) removeAttachment:(GalleryButton *)button
{

}

#pragma mark - RELOAD DATA

- (void) reloadData
{

}

#pragma mark - GALLERY BUTTON DELEGATE

-(void) touchDown
{
[self.delegate didPressButton];
}

-(void) touchUp
{
[self.delegate didDropButton];
_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

-(BOOL) isInsideRecycleBin:(GalleryButton *)button touching:(BOOL)finished;
{
CGPoint newLoc = [self convertPoint:self.recycleBin.frame.origin toView:self.mainView];
CGRect binFrame = self.recycleBin.frame;
binFrame.origin = newLoc;

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(binFrame, button.frame) == TRUE){
    if (finished){
        [self removeAttachment:button];
    }
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}

}

@end
```

**GalleryButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol GalleryButtonDelegate;

@interface GalleryButton : UIView
{

id<GalleryButtonDelegate> delegate;

CGPoint _originalPosition;
CGPoint _originalOutsidePosition;

BOOL isInScrollview;

// PARENT VIEW WHERE THE VIEWS CAN BE DRAGGED
UIView *mainView;
// SCROLL VIEW WHERE YOU GONNA PUT THE THUMBNAILS
UIScrollView *scrollParent;
UIImageView *images;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<GalleryButtonDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint originalPosition;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollParent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *images;
@end

@protocol GalleryButtonDelegate
-(void) touchDown;
-(void) touchUp;
-(BOOL) isInsideRecycleBin:(GalleryButton *)button touching:(BOOL)finished;
@end
```

**GalleryButton.m**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "GalleryButton.h"
#import "GalleryScrollView.h"
#import "AttachmentItem.h"

@implementation GalleryButton

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize originalPosition = _originalPosition;
@synthesize mainView, scrollParent;
@synthesize images;

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
}

return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self){

    isInScrollview  = YES;

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark - DRAG AND DROP

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[self.delegate touchDown];
self.originalPosition = self.center;
self.scrollParent.scrollEnabled = NO;

if (isInScrollview == YES) {
    CGPoint newLoc = CGPointZero;
    newLoc = [[self superview] convertPoint:self.center toView:self.mainView];
    _originalOutsidePosition = newLoc;

    //      [self.superview touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    [self removeFromSuperview];

    self.center = newLoc;
    [self.mainView addSubview:self];
    [self.mainView bringSubviewToFront:self];
    isInScrollview = NO;
}
else {
    ;
}

}

 -(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"stalk" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.001];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
self.center = [touch locationInView: self.superview];

[UIView commitAnimations];

if ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:NO]){

}

}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if ([delegate isInsideRecycleBin:self touching:YES]){

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300);
    images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light-cherry.png"]];
    [self.mainView addSubview:images];
    [self.images viewWithTag:1];

    UIImageView * animation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    animation.frame = CGRectMake(self.center.x - 32, self.center.y - 32, 40, 40);

    animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem3.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed: @"iconEliminateItem4.png"]
                                 ,nil];
    [animation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [animation setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    [animation startAnimating];
    [self.mainView addSubview:animation];
    [animation bringSubviewToFront:self.mainView];
    [animation release];
    ;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

} else{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"goback" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.center = _originalOutsidePosition;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    //        loadingView.frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 80, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

[self.delegate touchUp];

}

-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"goback"] && finished) {
    [self removeFromSuperview];
    self.center = _originalPosition;
    [self.scrollParent addSubview:self];
    isInScrollview = YES;
}
}

@end
```

Comment: Show the declaration of `[GalleryButton initWithFrame:imageName:]`.

Comment: @trojanfoe   How and where do I put this declaration? Excuse my idiocracy...

Comment: Just show the content of `GallerButton.h` (I assume that's where it's declared).

Comment: @trojanfoe   . sorry about this, But i'm still super confused as to why i'm getting this error, and how to fix this. Am I not declaring GalleryButton right in my GalleryButton.h ?

Comment: I don't know - that's my point - you haven't shown us its declaration yet.

Comment: @trojanfoe  Oh ok I will amend my question now with the gallery buttom.m and .h now.

Comment: @trojanfoe  I have now edited my question to include GalleryButton.h and .m  .  Thanks

Comment: @trojanfoe  I have also included a link to my xcode project..

Comment: @trojanfoe  I still get the error in GalleryScrollView.m  when I put - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName; in the GalleryButton.h file?

Comment: Have you built your app?

Comment: @trojanfoe  Yes. There is a link to my Xcode project in my question:)

Comment: I still don't see the declaration of `initWithFrame:imageName:` in `GalleryButton.h` of your project.  You uploaded this before my answer; did you update it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19433/discussion-between-blake-loizides-and-trojanfoe)

Comment: @trojanfoe  Ok I have updated my question with my new xcode project update:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. After killing myself trying I found my mistake.

I Used:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName;
```

In both the GalleryButton.h and GalleryScrollview.h and I just took it out of GalleryScrollview.h

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't declared the custom `init` method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString *)imageName;
```

In `GalleryButton.h`.  You also haven't implemented it in `GalleryButton.m`.  Perhaps you didn't mean to use this method at all in your code?

Either way you've referenced it and Xcode has correctly warned you that it doesn't exist (if you build and run the code you will get an *Unrecognized selector sent to instance* exception).

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `initWithFrame:image Name` in `GalleryButton` in its header file. Always remember, if you get a warning that's says something like "May not respond to..." It's because it's not publicly mentioned in the classes header file.